# Should battery count for laptop be a negative number

Tags: windows-10, battery-life

I have a Toshiba Satellite P55W-C5200X that dual boots Windows 10 and Ubuntu. I had to replace the battery, which is removed by opening the laptop's bottom (doesn't pop out), over 3 times. I bought the computer in 2015 December.

In Windows 10, I set the low battery level as 20%. But the notification never comes on. Reserve level is 25%, but the action never happens. The critical is 5%. The notifications/actions for reserve and low battery stopped occurring a few months ago.

My battery test (powercfg) shows I have a negative cycle count. Does this mean the battery is dying or that I need to recallibrate it?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unplug the machine, let it run on battery, let the battery level drop to below 20%. When that happens, shut down, plug in and start up. See if the battery level software has reset itself.

If it still shows as your screen shot, then it is time to replace the battery.

Batteries commonly last 3 to 5 years and you are at the end of that period.

Replacement batteries should be OEM Toshiba batteries. Issues with OEM batteries should be taken up with Toshiba Support (to determine if there is a hardware issue)

Comment: I bought the battery I am using in May 2020. But this is the 3rd battery that I bought. The other ones stopped charging. Does this mean I have a bad/poorly made laptop? Each battery was specifically made to fit my laptop.

Comment: Try the test I suggested to see if the battery re-calibrates or if it needs replacing. If a Toshiba battery, ask Toshiba support. If 3rd party, a one year life is not surprising.